# MySQL single row with multiple records

Tags: mysql, row, records, multiple-records

I have a table with contains multiple rows that define "amenities" for a particular resort. I need to return the resortID if there are rows containing whatever "amenOptionID" I define. My issue comes in where I'm looking to see if a resort has two or more amenities. For example:

I want to return resortIDs that have BOTH amenOptionID 1 AND 4. I also do not want duplicate resortIDs. Refer to the image for the table structure. Thanks in advance for any help.

[image: Table Structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  SELECT `resortID`
   WHERE `amenOptionID`
         IN (1, 4) 
GROUP BY `resortID`
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work...

```
SELECT resortID, COUNT(*) AS theCount FROM myTable WHERE amenOptionID IN(1,4) GROUP BY resortId HAVING theCount=2;
```